# How do you return a a set of matching rows and concatenate one of the columns?

Tags: excel, powerpivot, dax, powerquery

I want to do something like  this:

```
=related(othertable[aColumn])
```

But where there are multiple matching rows it should concatenate all of the `aColumn` values that match.

Something like this, but working:

```
=concatenate(values(filter(othertable,othertable[bColumn]=[value in this table])))
```

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't figure out how to do this in DAX so instead did it in Power Query.

```
//using this as a start:
aTable = #table({"A","B","C"},{{1,"a",1},{1,"b",2},{2,"c",3},{3,"d",4}}),
//I'm concatenating text...so need to have a function stating what to concatenate with
fCombine = Combiner.CombineTextByDelimiter(":"),
aGroupRowsCat = Table.Group( 
  aTable, 
  {"A"}, 
  {{"CatOfB", each fCombine([C]), type text}} 
)
```

I end up with:

```
A|CatOfB
-+------
1|a:b
2|c
3|d
```

Comment: awesome! was looking for something like this for quite some time :)

Answer (score 1):

Jason Thomas answered this question on his blog post [Group Multiple Rows to Single Delimited Row in PowerPivot](http://www.sqljason.com/2013/01/group-multiple-rows-to-single-delimited.html)

In that post he explains that if you first create a parent/child hierarchy then you can use [`PATH`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg492167.aspx) to return a comma separated list.

He uses the [`RANKX`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg492185.aspx) function and a little bit of logic to create the parent/child relationship, then calculates the parent value for the column of interest, and finally uses the `PATH` function to calculate the comma seperated list.